# Cell color change for edited cell content in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to change the color of a cell the content of which was just changed by the user. Do you have any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: DataGrid's cell edit ending event might help. Yet I am not sure, because in that event what we get is instance of DataGridCellInfo class. It is not the actual cell. I don't have my VS2010 with me :(

Comment: if you can put some more code or information it would help all of us over here to understand it in a better way :) :) just a suggestion